# Help re-factoring Ruby hash slicing and dicing

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm working on a project where I need to associate newspaper articles with the page numbers they appear on in print.

My input data is just a bunch of pairs of article titles and page numbers. I came up with the following code to create a new `Hash` where the keys are page numbers and the values are arrays of the article titles:

```
a = ["A1", "title 1"]
b = ["A1", "title 2"]
c = ["A2", "title 3"]
hash = {}
articles = [a,b,c]
articles.each do |a|
  if hash.has_key?(a[0])
    hash[a[0]] << a[1]
  else
    hash.merge!({a[0] => [a[1]]})
  end
end
```

The code works well enough, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this. I checked the Ruby docs and couldn't find any built in methods, but I'd like SO's input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Michael Kohl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220147/michael-kohl) has been reminding of [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001497) lately:

```
articles = [
    ["A1", "title 1"],
    ["A1", "title 2"],
    ["A2", "title 3"]
]
page_to_titles = articles.group_by(&:first).each { |k,v| v.map!(&:last) }
```

Works the same in 1.9.2 and 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

```
articles.inject(Hash.new) do |hash, (page, title)|
  h[page] ||= []
  h[page] << title
  h
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[a,b,c].inject(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |res,(p,t)| res[p] << t; res }
```

or only for ruby 1.9:

```
[a,b,c].each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(p,t),res| res[p] << t }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be more descriptive with what you do and use a guard `||=` for instead of `if`. I would refactor it like this:

```
articles = []
articles << ["A1", "title 1"] 
articles << ["A1", "title 2"]
articles << ["A2", "title 3"]

PAGE = 0
TITLE = 1

def merge_articles(articles)
  res = {}
  articles.each do |a|
    res[a[PAGE]] ||= []
    res[a[PAGE]] << a[TITLE] 
  end
  res
end

hash = merge_articles(articles)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Ruby 1.9:

```
articles.inject({}) do |hash, (page, title)|
  hash.tap do |h|
    h[page] ||= []
    h[page] << title
  end
end
```